# Unable to perform "cde data download" in Windows 10 using ChemDataExtractor

Tags: python, powershell, anaconda

I am trying to install the package "ChemDataExtractor" (http://chemdataextractor.org/docs/install). I have managed to install in using Anaconda. According to the page, I need to execute `cde data download` in order get the data files, which I'm unable perform in Windows Powershell / Command Prompt. I encounter the following error:

```
cde : The term 'cde' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ cde data download
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (cde:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 0):

This is only to install the other required files. The command cde needs ChemDataExtractor to be installed.

The best way to do it is the following:

1. **Install PIP**
   First you want to install pip over this link: https://pypi.org/project/pip/
2. **Download ChemDataExtractor**
   Then you can use the simple command `pip install ChemDataExtractor` to install the CDE

Please let me know if it worked, and mark it as the answer if it did. :)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have tried to do so. I am encountering an error ```failed to create process```. Probably this is an issue of a different kind. Any ideas on how to get by? Thanks

Comment: I am sorry I probably can't help you with this issue.